# Bootstrap 4: How to horizontally align elements inside a drop-down?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a `dropdown` with 3 main "categories" inside, and each "category" has several checkboxes (this is being used to filter a search).
Here's an example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Category 1:</h6>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a>

        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Category 2:</h6>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a>

        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Category 3:</h6>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the 3 "categories" to be side by side, however, by default, in Bootstrap's `dropdown` class they're presented as a vertical stack.
I have tried to take advantage of the grid system by adding the `row` class to the `dropdown` and creating a `col-4` for each main "category" but the result was null. How can I put them side by side, having each one its own checkboxes below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap everything in one `<div class="dropdown-item">`. Then put a `.row` inside and put 3 `.col` inside that row. Finally, put each list group including the heading inside their corresponding column.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: you'd need to replace the `a` tags with `label`s for the checkboxes in order for them to trigger the checkboxes on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe I didn't make myself clear. That solution does exactly the opposite of what I want: it presents the categories as a vertical stack and the options horizontally aligned, while what I want is to have the categories horizontally aligned and the options vertically stacked.

Comment: Replacing the anchors with labels does not make this usable. So, while the layout is achieved, the user experience is sub-par.

Comment: This solution would work, but I just realized why it isn't working for me: the dropdown I'm trying to create is also a "col-3" in my code, wich makes everything inside it have a maximum width - including the dropdown menu. Knowing this, is there any way to make this work?
And about the anchors, I noticed that when I wrote the question, just didn't bother changing it, but thanks a lot.

Comment: If it's `col-3`, then where are you expecting to fill all that horizontal content into?? I can't do "black magic"! Normal magic is all I can.

Comment: @AndréPereira Have I answered your question?

Comment: @WebDevBooster Yes, I know that, my apologies.
However, for example, if you wanted a sentence to be written inside a div and at the same time you didn't want it to be restricted to the width of such div, you would use the "text-nowrap" class, right? Is there any way to imitate this effect with the dropdown menu?

Comment: @AndréPereira This has now become a different question and we are not supposed to ask/answer multiple questions in one according to the rules of Stack Overflow. Please first accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it (and feel free to give it an upvote if you like) and then post the new question as a separate question. I'll gladly post an answer to that as well.